# java not waiting for unix binary to complete execution

Tags: java, unix, binary, execution

Im creating a javafx application to run a unix binary application, which limits the percent of cpu a process can use, herein i already have a cputhrottle unix binary which receives PID and CPU percentage as argument, my application just acts as a GUI for this unix binary.

When I run this cputhrottle from terminal it keeps on running, until i press - CTRL+C (this is the normal behavior).

But the problem is, when I run this unix binary with my java code, it seems, as if the program is almost immediately terminated (whereas it should be running, until I press the stop button), and because its not running & being terminated, My program cannot control the percentage of CPU a process gets.

Here's my code : http://pastebin.com/rbG3ctfH

so, is there a way to tell java to keep running the cputhrottle binary file, instead of closing it.

I've tried replacing the 56th line, and instead wrote code to execute a script, which would create a file, with some text content, & when executed he program, it did created a file, so its working, but when i add e1.printStackTrace in the catch block, it stops working for some reason.

And also, if I add sleep  in the shell script, then its not executed Properly, more over no Exception is being Generated.

Comment: You are ignoring all exceptions so the problem is most likely that the command fails and throws an exception which you newer print/log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are trying to run ("echo dkkdk|sudo....) is a shell command.   You need to tell runtime.exec() to run 'bash -c echo dkkdk|sudo..'

Also be aware that runtime.exec is asynchronous and could/might/likely will return to your program before the child process completes.

Also, I could not pipe the superuser password to sudo like you are trying to do.  Not saying it doesn't work for you just that I couldn't get my system to take it.

Comment: bash -c, doesn't show any difference, I need to somehow Synchronize this process, thank you